# What is the meaning of "social" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives, interpretation

In the context of the following sentence:

> *He's not feeling very **social** this evening.*

I have considered the following explanations for ***social*** based on dictionary definitions:

- He wants to remain alone this evening.
- He does not fancy spending time with other people this evening.

Have I understood the meaning of 'social' correctly?

Comment: Yes - although **sociable** would be more usual.

Comment: In the context of a party, it means outgoing, talkative. having a friendly attitude.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between your two bullet points. (Perhaps I'm missing some subtlety.) In any case, you should use a dictionary and, if that doesn't answer your question, explain why not.

Comment: @KateBunting Surprisingly, 'social' as an adjective being used as a direct synonym of 'sociable' predates the use of 'social' as a noun by a few hundred years (according to https://www.etymonline.com/word/social). This was contrary to my initial thought that the adjectival form of social is a modern invention to the extent of arguably being an erroneous substitute for 'sociable'.